# List of REST API's for Magento-1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api, application

We have worked on the Magento-1.9.1.1 version website on the Porto theme. The website is working fine. Now we want to make a mobile application for Android/IOS.

For that, we hired app developers and they are working on react-native(for both android and IOS).
They need REST APIs to build the app.

I have referred to the following  :
[Devdocs tutorial for Rest API](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html)

It's good and giving the basics apis. But, App developers are asking API for login and sign up, etc.

Can anyone give the list of REST APIs which are generally using for the Mobile application?

And give me the solution to create them.

Comment: Have you refereed this url ? `https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html`

Comment: Because i am developing the same in Magento 2.2.4 and Dev docs helped me a lot and i am half way :) now.

Comment: @AdityaShah, I have already checked this and when i check this, i felt wah i'm safe. But, my developers are asking api for login and sign up etc.  Then i am getting stress. Thats yy i posted

Comment: In magento 2 there's API for Login and Register so there must be for Magento 1

Comment: And dw bro :) it will done

Comment: Yes, it should be for magento 1 also, I dont know that is. Thats y i am asking.

Can you show api for M2?

Comment: Yeah sure wait, i am posting but don't do down-vote, Because it's for M2 :D

Answer (score 0):

Magento has built in REST APIs for most of the features like products, customers, inventory, customer address, orders. You can find more information on the [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html) here.

Here are few REST URLs

Base URL for REST APIs: http://YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/api/rest

- http://magentohost/api/rest/products
- http://magentohost/api/rest/products/:productId/categories
- http://magentohost/api/rest/products/:productId/images
- http://magentohost/api/rest/products/:productId/websites
- http://magentohost/api/rest/customers
- http://magentohost/api/rest/customers/:customerId/addresses
- http://magentohost/api/rest/stockitems
- http://magentohost/api/rest/orders
- http://magentohost/api/rest/orders/:orderId/items
- http://magentohost/api/rest/orders/:orderid/addresses
- http://magentohost/api/rest/orders/:orderid/comments

You need to use oAuth to authenticate the APIs. [Learn more here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html#OAuthAuthentication-UsingOAuth).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good. when i run http://magentohost/api/rest/customers, Access denied.
And i need api for login and sign up also

Comment: You may need to configure Magento REST API in the admin panel before you would like to consume. Please check this [link](https://inchoo.net/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/) to configure the REST API and oAuth settings.

Comment: Please let me know if you can use the above inchoo article to setup the REST API and settings.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara Can you please check this git hub repo
https://github.com/leoliew/magento-api it has login and user register APIs.

Comment: I have just checked and installed into my website. But everything is showing in chinese language even it is en

Comment: its completely in Chinese

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara I am sorry for that.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara will this be helpful for you? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/customer/customer.create.html I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the available Rest API's in the magento by entering URL as

URL - ***{{MagentoHomepage}}/swagger***

Example: *http://lh.magento242.com/swagger*